# Content API for Shopping with Java OAuth

Tags: java, oauth, google-content-api

I went threw the "Getting Started"-documentation https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/quickstart by Google.

I'm getting stuck at the "Authorization" part:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessTokenRequest.GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl;
```

Here I'm getting the error msg: "Cannot resolve symbol 'draft10'"

```
import com.google.api.services.content.ShoppingContent;
```

There I'm getting the rror msg: "Cannot resolve symbol 'services'"

I'm using Gradle to get the packages:

```
compile "com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.18.0-rc"
```

I can't find a running code snipped. Has someone here some advice for me?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this Guide by google :

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-shopping-samples/blob/master/java/BaseSample.java